# Element's position().top does not change after scroll - how to get the new position?

Tags: jquery

I need to get an element's (a div) position (position().top) when the user scrolls the window. The problem is that when I call position().top to get the new position after scrolling, it's got the same value as before scrolling. Here's a bit of code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    alert($('#my-element').position().top);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        alert($('#my-element').position().top);
    });
});
```

How come it doesn't change? Is there a way to get the new fresh value?

Comment: The value is accurate; your understanding of [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) is wrong. Perhaps you want to subtract [`$(window).scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) from the `position().top`?

Comment: @Blazemonger  This is an answer (and the right one at that).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Problem is scrollTop() always returns 0, so there's not much I can do with that.

Comment: Perhaps you're calling `scrollTop()` on the element instead of the window? Try this: `$(window).scroll(function() { console.log($(window).scrollTop()); })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `.scrollTop()`.

*The scrollTop() method sets or returns the vertical scrollbar position for the selected elements.*

Read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp).

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y42uw/) of what you need.

As per gustavohenke, you should use .`offset()` instead since `.position()` is relative to it's parent. `.offset()` is relative to the document window.

Comment: More specifically, you need `position` in combination with `$(window).scrollTop()`.

Comment: Depending on what he wants exactly, yes, he'll probably have to substract the .position().top

Comment: Your edit just made this answer completely wrong.  `$("div").scrollTop()` will give how much the content within the div has scrolled.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery's `.position()` return is relative to the element's offset parent.

You probably should use `.offset().top`, which will calculate relative to the document, and then discount from it the document scroll size.

```
$( "#my-element" ).offset().top - $( document ).scrollTop()
```

Comment: `position()` is relative to the "offset parent", which is a bit different than just the parent.  Though I agree `offset()` is safer.